# Can I access excel file from a remote sharepoint server in my Excel Web Access web part?

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-enterprise, excel-services

We are developing an organization level dashboard in which we are using Excel Web Access web part to display part of or entire excel workbooks containing charts. Problem is, the corresponding actual excel files to be used here are stored on a seperate SharePoint server, within the same company intranet. We need to access excel files from this seperate portal on a different server from the excel web access we part. It gives error. Anyone has done anything similar to this?

Comment: how you trying to access files at the moment and what error you get.

Comment: I am trying to access excel file lying on some different sharepoint server(outside the current farm) but within the same organization intranet. Get error something like 'file can not be found'. i have added this remote url to trusted connections.